# jquery plugin cannot access object referenced in plugin definition

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin that would react to any changes on some input fields within a dom element that i choose.

my plugin definition is as follows:

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) { 
            console.log(this.obj);
            var inputs = $('input', this.obj);
            $.each(inputs, function(i, domElement){
                $(this.obj).premiumUpdatable('addEvent', $(domElement));
            })

        },
        addEvent: function(element){
            $(element).bind('change',function(){
                console.log($(element).val());
            })
        }
    };

    $.fn.premiumUpdatable = function( method ) {

        return this.each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.premiumUpdatable' );
            }    
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then I call my plugin like:

```
$('div.updatable').premiumUpdatable();
```

Problem is that when i try console.log(this.obj) in one of the methods defined i always get undefined. I wish to get the reference that i made in the definition of the plugin, obj = $(this); ...i wish to get the $(this) element.

I need this plugin applied to a number of dom elements on the page but if i can't get the reference to the dom element ...i can't really tell which is which....

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

PS: I may not be asking the right questions as I am still new to developing plugins in jquery but this problem seems to really bug me and I can't overcome it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped your Code into the most solid plugin structure for jquery plugins I could find so far. This will also sort out your problem not being able to access the object inside your plugin scope

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $.premiumUpdatable = function(el, options){
                // set a reference to the class instance
                var base = this,
                    // store all inputs for reuse
                    inputs;

                // store the options in base.o
                base.o = $.extend({},$.premiumUpdatable.defaultOptions, options);
                // set a reference to the jquery object
                base.$el = $(el);
                // set a reference to the DOMNode
                base.el = el;

                /**
                 * @public
                 * This function can be accessed from outside the plugin scope with
                 * $('.premium').data('premiumUpdatable').publicFunction();
                 */
                this.publicFunction = function(){};

                var initInputs = function(){
                    inputs = $( 'input', base.$el.attr('id') ).each( function( i, domElement ){
                        $( domElement ).bind( 'change', function(){
                            console.log( 'input ' + $( this ).attr('id') + ' changed to: ', $( this ).val() );
                        });
                    });
                };

                /**
                 * @private
                 * self-executing constructor
                 */
                (function init(){
                    initInputs();
                })();
            };
            // defining the default options here makes it posible to change them globaly with
            // $.premiumUpdatable.defaultOption.myValue = 'value'
            // or
            // $.premiumUpdatable.defaultOption = { myValue:'value' }
            // before the first initialisation for the objects to come
            $.premiumUpdatable.defaultOptions = {};
            $.fn.premiumUpdatable = function(options){
                return this.each(function( index, element ){
                    // prevents a second initialisation of the object if data('premiumUpdatable') is already set
                    if ( undefined == $( element ).data('premiumUpdatable') ) {
                        // stores a referenze to the PluginClass, to that your able to access its public function from outside with
                        // $('.premium').data('premiumUpdatable').publicFunction();
                        $( element ).data('premiumUpdatable', new $.premiumUpdatable( element, options));
                    }
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $( document ).ready( function(){
           $('.premium').premiumUpdatable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="premium">
       <form>
           <input id="inputText" type="text" value="" /><br />
           <input id="inputPassword" type="password" value="" /><br />
           <input id="inputCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="something checked" /><br />
           <input id="inputRadio" type="radio" value="1" />
       </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this to call the `init()` method:

```
return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
```

`this` is the current DOM element, and you obviously expect in the `init()` method `this` to be your plugin instance.

Another problem is that your `obj` property is declared withint the `.each()` callback, so it won't be visible in the `init()` method anyway.

The link here proposes a base structure for developing jquery plugins:
[jQuery plugin boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)

---

Complementary to the plugin development, here are some links about the 'this' keyword in javascript. It's pretty important to really understand it I think to not end up in uncomprehensible situations while developing:

[The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
[What is ‘this’ in JavaScript?](http://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/)
[BETTER JAVASCRIPT–WHAT IS THIS?](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2011/06/better-javascriptwhat-is-this.html)